# git jargon and publishing first app on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

So I have made a simple Sinatra/Ruby app that I can run on my localhost. I got a heroku account trying to publish my app. Through my learning process I have come across a lot of jargon, like: git, push, repo, branches, etc. To be honest I have no idea what these mean.

For now, I just want to publish my simple app and have it running/share with, say, my friend in Croatia!

Heroku is a host, Git is a version control system. How are the 2 connected?

For now I need to publish my first happ and see it running with the needed commands so I get an idea how this thing works.

Any help?

Comment: Have you read the [Heroko help article "Deploying with Git"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)?

Comment: but i'm stuck at this point where after typing `git push heroku master` i get this error: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original poster's comments:

> but i'm stuck at this point where after typing `git push heroku master` i get this error:
>
> > Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

It sounds like you might not have your SSH keys set up for Heroku.  You can find the instructions for that at [Managing Your SSH Keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys).  Here's what the instructions tell you to do:

#### 1. Generate a public key

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.

Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa):

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 

Your identification has been saved in /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
a6:88:0a:0b:74:90:c6:e9:d5:49:d6:e3:04:d5:6c:3e adam@workstation.local
```

> Press enter at the first prompt to use the default file location. You may wish to provide a password for the key, although this is not necessary - if your workstation is physically secure and is not used by anyone other than you, pressing enter at both prompts to make a passwordless key is secure. As long as you keep the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` secret, your key will be secure even without a password.

#### 2. Add keys to Heroku

> The first time you run the `heroku` command, you’ll be prompted for your credentials. Your public key will then be automatically uploaded to Heroku. This will allow you to deploy code to all of your apps.
>
> A common key error is: `Permission denied (publickey)`. You can fix this by using `keys:add` to notify Heroku of your new key.

Answer (score 0):

When first starting with Heroku there are a few simple steps to do before you deploy your application on Heroku.

1) Create an account on Heroku https://go.heroku.com/ and download the Heroku Toolbelt https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

2) Authenticate yourself with Heroku and upload a public key using the command:

```
heroku login
```

If you do not have a public key, the above command will ask you if you want to create one.  Say yes and Heroku will generate a new key.

You can also generate your own public key and use the heroku keys:add command to add that key if you prefer.  Using public keys is common practice for services that use Git, such as Github.

3) Create your application code (eg. in Java, Node.js, Scala, Clojure, Ruby, Rails, Python, Django)

4) Version your application code using git with the commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "new project created"
```

Note that git add . will add everything, you can be more selective using specific filenames or filename patterns rather than full stop.

5) Create a place for your application on Heroku.  This creates a remote repository to push your code to as well as a URL for your application.

```
heroku create
```

6) Deploy your application to Heroku.  As Heroku uses Git as a way to copy your code from your local machine to the Heroku servers you push the commits you made locally to Heroku using the Git command.

```
git push heroku master
```

7) Depending on how you run your application, you may also need to define a text file called Procfile that specifies the commands to run your application.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Once you have deployed your application successfully, all you should need to do from then on is commit your changes locally and push them to Heroku, as shown in steps 4 and 6.

Thank you.